# Infinite horizontal scroll within div is not working? CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS and I'm currently interested in creating infinite scrolling text within a div in my code, yet for some reason no matter what I do it won't work? I'm unsure of how to approach the issue after hours of searching on stack overflow.

Here is the bit of my code that is struggling:

```css
#interior-right {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid orange 2px;
  margin-left: 110%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 600px;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.interior-right p {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 150px;
  line-height: 170px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="interior-right">
  ALL WORK AND NO PLAY MAKES
</div>
```

Comment: You've got a lot of styles for the p in the div, but you're missing the p itself. Also, a marquee is not what is normally meant by "infinite scrolling".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this... height of the div will increase depends on the content if you give `height : auto;`. And if you want to set minimum height, give like `min-height: 1000px;`

```
#interior-right {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```